# Laravel loop throught an column in database and perform action

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Let's get to it.

I have an command in laravel:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Entity;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Ixudra\Curl\Facades\Curl;

class DownloadIcal extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'ical:download';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Download all ICAL files from ical field in businesses database';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {

        $urls = Entity::pluck('ical');
        $ids = Entity::pluck('id');
        foreach ($urls as $url) {
        if($url === null){
            print_r("test");
        }else{
        $response = Curl::to($url);
            foreach ($response as $test) {
                foreach ($ids as $id) {
            >download('public/ical/'.$id.'.ics');
            $this->info("ICal Retrieved");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

So what I want to do is retrieve ical column in entity table and id it belongs to, take a value of ical if not null (it is an url) and download it public/ical with a name as the id of that specific entity.

However I am not sure how to do that correctly. Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to accomplish:

```
$entities = Entity::pluck('ical', 'id');

foreach ( $entities as $entityID => $entityIcal ) {
    $response = Curl::to($entityIcal);

    foreach ($response as $test) {
        >download('public/ical/'.$entityID.'.ics');
        $this->info("ICal Retrieved");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting unexpected -> here's the package used just in case : https://github.com/ixudra/curl

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas you should finish your `>download` line, I don't know how this package works.